# Name of false answer effect in surveys

Tags: social-psychology, measurement, bias, survey

I'm looking for research I've read about a well known effect that happens when participants complete a survey, where they do not answer what they think is right, but what they think the researchers are expecting from them.
It can be a survey but it can also be something else...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called "[demand characteristics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_characteristics)":

> ... an experimental artifact where participants form an interpretation
>   of the experiment's purpose and unconsciously change their behavior to
>   fit that interpretation.

An example is:

> The good-participant role in which the participant attempts to discern
>   the experimenter's hypotheses and to confirm them. The participant
>   does not want to "ruin" the experiment.

Demand characteristics are a type of [response bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Response_bias):

> ... a general term for a wide range of cognitive biases that influence
>   the responses of participants away from an accurate or truthful
>   response. These biases are most prevalent in the types of studies and
>   research that involve participant self-report, such as structured
>   interviews or surveys.

Another related type of response bias is the "[social desirability bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_desirability_bias)":

> ... the tendency of survey respondents to answer questions in a manner
>   that will be viewed favorably by others.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thx